# Process 'system/bin/installd' causing memory leak

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, ram, oneplus-one, processes

When reviewing my running tasks, I've noticed a memory leak in process `system/bin/installd`. On boot completed, it begins running in the background, consuming 20-30MB RAM. Over time, its RAM usage gradually increases, going as high as 400MB at which time it causes a random reboot.

I am able force kill this process with no noticeable effects. However, it does restart itself and continue to leak memory.

Before I can attempt to remedy this issue, I need to know exactly what `system/bin/installd` is/what it does - something I cannot seem to find any information on.

Can anyone help?

Specs:

- OnePlus One (rooted)
- Mahdi ROM (CM11 base), Android 4.4.4 KitKat
- Build # KTU84Q
- Kernel 3.4.0-Mahdi-One-kk
- Running multiple Xposed modules, init tweaks, etc.

Comment: May I know how did you detect that process was leaking memory? I never know if it's possible to check memory usage for non-APK.

Comment: @AndrewT. I am using "3C Toolbox Pro"; it's task manager displays all running processes. I highly recommend it- it's a great app with tons of tools for power users.

Answer (score 1):

`/system/bin/installd` is a system daemon that is involved in the installation of applications. System classes like `PackageInstaller` use it in their execution.

This article from [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/depth-android-package-manager) dates back to 2013, but it gives some pointers that can put on track:

> PackageInstaller is the default application for Android to interactively install a normal package. PackageInstaller provide user interface to manage applications/packages. PackageInstaller calls InstallAppProgress activity to receive instructions from the user. InstallAppProgress will ask Package Manager Service to install package via installd. Source code is available at  /packages/apps/PackageInstaller.

Today's Android code states (for example: `services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/Installer.java`):

```
 public void onStart() {
    Slog.i(TAG, "Waiting for installd to be ready.");
    mInstaller.waitForConnection();
}
```

The same file comments on checking out `frameworks/native/cmds/installd/installd.h` (I did not look further for now).

In short, you may need to look at the source code to know more about `installd`, depending on what you are up to.